# Calculating NETWORKDAYS using a CalendarTable SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff

Previously I created a SELECT to calculate Business Days (Weekends/Holydays) which didn't work for certain date ranges for each records. I was suggested to use a Calendar Table, which actually worked for other requirements I had on hold but I can't figure how to calculate `INI` and `END` for business days.

I've tried to do a SELECT with a semi left join and a join (suggested as well) but it doesn't seem to calculate at all.

This is the Calendar Table:

```
CalendarId  DateValue               DayNumberOfWeek NameOfDay  NameOfMonth WeekOfYear  JulianDay   USAIsBankHoliday USADayName
----------- ----------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- -------------------
20100101    2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 5               Viernes    Enero       1           1           1                Año nuevo
```

My table:

```
INI                            FIN                            DD --DATEDIFF BETWEEN DATES
------------------------------ ------------------------------ -----------
20180129                       20180211                       14
```

My attempt at calculating business days

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,INI,112) AS INI, 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR,FIN,112) AS FIN, 
    DATEDIFF(DD, INI, FIN)+1 AS DD 
FROM HISTORICOLICMED T
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM CALENDAR C
    WHERE T.INI = C.CALENDARID and T.FIN = C.CALENDARID
    AND C.USAISBANKHOLIDAY = 0 BETWEEN T.INI AND T.FIN)
```

I expect getting the correct business day calculations including holidays so for the example above I will get something like:

```
INI                            FIN                            DD     ND
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----- -----
20180129                       20180211                       14     10
```

Comment: Your table can't have two columns named `INI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-Select the count of rows in the calendar table that are between `INI` and `FIN` and are business days.

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,INI,112) AS INI, 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR,FIN,112) AS FIN, 
    DATEDIFF(DD, INI, FIN)+1 AS DD, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CalendarTable WHERE ...) AS ND
FROM HISTORICOLICMED
```

Comment: Subselecting `USABANKHOLIDAYS` doesn't display the the non working days. `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,INI,112) AS INI, 
 CONVERT(NVARCHAR,FIN,112) AS FIN, 
 DATEDIFF(DD, INI, FIN)+1 AS DD 
FROM HISTORICOLICMED T
WHERE EXISTS
(
 SELECT COUNT(USAISBANKHOLIDAY) AS D
 FROM CALENDAR C
 WHERE C.CALENDARID BETWEEN T.INI AND T.FIN
)`

Comment: No, don't use EXISTS at all.   Make your fourth column a subselect.   See my edit.

Comment: I can't convert INI or FIN because I'm getting an `Msg 8115` even if I convert it to other datatypes like int or varchar (I'm guessing because CALENDARID is int?)

Comment: Instead of `CalendarID BETWEEN INI and FIN`, use `DateValue`

Answer (score 2):

Proposed solution:

```
set datefirst 1;
select INI
    ,FIN
    , DATEDIFF(DD, INI, FIN)+1 as DD
    ,(DATEDIFF(DD, INI, FIN)+1)
    -(DATEDIFF(WK, INI, FIN)*2)
    -(case DATEPART(DW, INI)    when 7 then 1 else 0 end)
    -(case DATEPART(DW, FIN)    when 6 then 1 else 0 end)
    -(select COUNT(*) from CALENDAR
        where DateValue between INI and FIN
        and USAIsBankHoliday = 1)
    as ND -- Working days except US Bank holidays
from HISTORICOLICMED;
```